# React Redux - call dispatch without connect (not from a react component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a scheduled function which fetches data from the server every x minutes and i want it to update the state with the response:

```
api.fetchData().then(
    (response) => {
        dispatch(Actions.updateConfiguration(response));
    }
};
```

This function should not be a react component since it doesn't render anything.

However i can't seem to figure out how to inject `dispatch` function without using `connect`, which requires it to be a react component.

Thanks.

Comment: Just call it directly on the store: `store.dispatch(Actions.updateConfiguration(response))`

Comment: Plenty of options here: 1) Use `store.dispatch` directly. 2) Use `redux-saga` to implement a long-running task that will start and stop data fetching. 3) Do create component that acts as data provider to its children.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've a similar thing (A recurring check on wether the auth token is still valid) and we did the following.

In our little "util" function we receive the redux store as a parameter

```
export function startSessionTimer(store) {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        if ( ... ) {
            store.dispatch( ... );
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }, (15 * 60 * 1000));
}
```

Then, where we set up our app and create the store, we also kick-start the timer.

```
const store = configureStore( ... );
startSessionTimer(store);
```